# Unique random item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, unique

In JavaScript, I would like to randomly remove an item from an array and display this within the HTML on a button click.
Then on the next click of the button show the next removed item from the array. However, this doesn't seem to be working!

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bs4e5g69/

```
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function() {
  var count = 3;
  var myArray = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G'
  ];
  var tmpArrayE = myArray.slice(myArray);
  var goE = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var optionsE = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpArrayE.length);
    var removedE = tmpArrayE.splice(optionsE, 1);

    goE.push(removedE[0]);
  }
  document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = goE[0];
}
```

Comment: Would you like to remove the element from the original list? Or just show random elements from the list?

Comment: `slice` is used to get a portion of an array as a new array. But what are you trying to do with `myArray.splice(myArray)`?

Comment: probably removedE instead of goE[0]

Comment: you want to display each element exactly once, or can they repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining your array in your event handler, so your array will never be empty !

Here is your updated code :

```
// myArray initial content, as a global variable : 
  var myArray = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G'
  ];

  // the event handler, randomly emptying myArray one at a time : 
  document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function() {
    // check for an empty array : 
    if (myArray.length > 0) {
      var optionsE = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
      var removedE = myArray.splice(optionsE, 1);
      document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = removedE[0];
    } else {
      alert("the array is now empty");
    }
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs4e5g69/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `myArray` inside onclick function. So on every click it will create an new array.

```js
var myArray = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G'
];
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function() {
  //check if myArray length is greater than 0
  if (myArray.length > 0) {
    // generate random number
    var optionsE = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    // remove that element & show in div
    var removedE = myArray.splice(optionsE, 1);
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = removedE;
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="Button">
  Start
</button>
<div id="Answer">
  Result
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, for some reason it didn't even cross my mind to put the array outside the function! Moving it outside the function fixed all the issues thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use a copy of `myArray`, you need to move this line outside of the callback, because you get always a (new) copy for every event.

```
var tmpArrayE = myArray.slice(0); // myArray.slice(myArray) is wrong.
```

For using the original array in the callback, you could just use `myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Start by shuffling the array.  Then pop the last element off when one is needed.

Plan B:  Pick a random element from 0 to len-1.  Copy the last element into that slot.  Then shorten the array by one.

If you need a "shuffle" function, do this (only N steps; result is random):

```
for j = 0..N-1
     swap item #j with item # rand(0..N-1)
```